# Infinite exponential sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

[image: The problem]

Hi, I’ve been trying to crack this problem but I’m unable to make any progress, could you please give me hints? Thx

Edit: The solution is from wolframalpha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{(an)^ie^{-an}e^{-i/n}}{i!}=e^{-an} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{(ane^{-1/n})^i}{i!}=e^{-an} e^{ane^{-1/n}}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I should revisit stuff like this as I’ve apparently forgotten a lot.